# which file is updated the parent or the child with diskpart merge

Tags: windows-7, vhd

It seems that using diskpart merge to merge a differencing drive and parent does not provide an option to target a new VHD file.  Fine, I've backed up my parent vhd files, and the child.

When I execute the merge will the parents remain unmodified, or will they have the content of the child merged in them.

I need the child VHD to be standalone, but the other child vhd to continue to work off the parent.

What bit of documentation I have been able to find, is not clear as which direction the data flows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data flows back into the parent.  You won't get what you want directly from diskpart.

What you want is to mount the differencing chain and duplicate the contents into a new VHD.  That can be done most easily by creating a new VHD and copying the contents of the old child, mounted.